# how to limit the number of entries in the for loop php

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model and ready-made data in a table. In this model, I added a new field and made a connection with another table.

And in order not to manually fill in these fields for each record, I want to create a migration that will automatically fill in this field for all records.

Relationship table has two fields: post_id and author_id.

I am trying to do like this:

```
$posts = Posts::find()->all();

foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $index; $j++, $i++) {
        if ($j >= 4) {
          $j = 0;
        }
        $item = new PostAuthor();
        $item->setAttribute('post_id', $posts->id);
        $item->setAttribute('author_id', $j + 1);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

Everything also works as it should, but there is one problem, when the counter reaches 4, then the author_id is added again to the same post, starting from one.

I am attaching a screenshot, what should not be circled at all, when the counter reaches 4, then the post does not need to add an author_id anymore

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
if ($j >= 4) {
  $j = 0;
}
```

does nothing other than set `$j = 0`. The loop carries on as-written.

If you want the loop to halt here, then you have two options:

```
foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $index; $j++, $i++) {
        if ($j >= 4) {
          break;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $index, $j < 4; $j++, $i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Though at this point `$i` and `$j` are functionally identical and you can simply throw one of them away and put an `&&` in the loop boundary condition.

```
foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $index && $i < 4; $i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the post where I wrote a detailed answer